# learn to convert a json object into a java script and show output in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, object

I need to learn to convert JSON Object to javascript.
In below JSON there are 2 columns, how will I iterate both columns.
Kindly help me out.

```
{

    "hotels": {

        "1":{"name": "Taj Residency","description":" Sample description of Taj" },

    "2":{"name": "Gulf Zone","description":" Sample description of Gulf Zone"},

    "3":{"name": "Silver Resort","description":" Sample description of Silver Resort"},

    "4":{"name": "Burj Al Arab","description":" Sample description of Burj Al Arab "},

    "5":{"name": "Raffles Dubai","description":" Sample description of Raffles Dubai"},

    "6":{"name": "Dubai Heights","description":" Sample description of Dubai Heights"},

    "7":{"name": "Classic Tower","description":" Sample description of Classic Tower"},

    "8":{"name": "Royal","description":" Sample description of Royal"},

    "9":{"name": "Al Arab Residency","description":" Sample description of Al Arab Residency"}

    },

"location": {

    "1":{"name": "Dubai" },

"2":{"name": "Sharjah"},

"3":{"name": "Abu Dhabi"},

"4":{"name": "Mumbai"}

}

}
```

I am able to watch my output on the console of the browser, but unable to show it on the browser.

Please check with below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'jSon.json',
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log(response);

                }
            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some pedantry: no such thing as JSON object; JSON is a string; it may be converted to a JavaScript object (from which the name JSON derives.) As for outputting it to HTML, you need to iterate over it with loops and create DOM elements. Did you try anything?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what you tried to show in browser

Comment: JSON is Javascript (JavaScript Object Notation), what are you trying to do with your JSON? Have you tried JSON.parse()? We need more information.

Comment: @Jelmer - no need for `.parse()` as he's parsing it via jQuery.

Comment: i can see objects Hotels and Location in the console. and same objects i want into output like warp in ordered List.

Comment: please visit te link http://proittechnology.com/dev/assign/
and open console you will see 2 objects. same object i want to wrap or iterate into unordered list.

Comment: More pedantry: no such thing as a java script. I guess you mean a JavaScript program. You don't "convert" JSON or a JavaScript object into JavaScript, but you may use JavaScript to create DOM elements based on it.

Comment: yes how to create DOM based element? Please help?

Comment: @Utkanos - JSON isn't always a string, although it can be transmitted as one. Just remember what the O stands for.

Comment: @HarshadPatil - You seem like you need to read/watch some tutorials on basic js/jquery before asking these questions.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - yes, it stands for "object" but is qualified by the next word, "notation", i.e. the notation (serialisation) of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code to show on browser

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'jSon.json',
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    //console.log(data);
$('div.hotels').append('<div></div>').append("<h3>Hotels</h3>");
        $('div.locations').append('<div></div>').append("<h3>Locations</h3>");
        $.each(data.hotels,function(i,item){
          $('div.hotels').append('<ul></ul>').append("<li>"+item.name+"</li>").append("<li>"+item.description+"</li>");
    });

        $.each(data.location,function(i,item){
          $('div.locations').append('<ul></ul>').append("<li>"+item.name+"</li>");
       });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="myClass">
<div class="hotels"></div>
<div class="Locations"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice :) expecting same output.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get started. Here `var json` is the `response` from your ajax request.

```js
var json = '{"hotels": {"1":{"name": "Taj Residency","description":" Sample description of Taj" },"2":{"name": "Gulf Zone","description":" Sample description of Gulf Zone"},"3":{"name": "Silver Resort","description":" Sample description of Silver Resort"},"4":{"name": "Burj Al Arab","description":" Sample description of Burj Al Arab "},"5":{"name": "Raffles Dubai","description":" Sample description of Raffles Dubai"},"6":{"name": "Dubai Heights","description":" Sample description of Dubai Heights"},"7":{"name": "Classic Tower","description":" Sample description of Classic Tower"},"8":{"name": "Royal","description":" Sample description of Royal"},"9":{"name": "Al Arab Residency","description":" Sample description of Al Arab Residency"}},"location": {"1":{"name": "Dubai" },"2":{"name": "Sharjah"},"3":{"name": "Abu Dhabi"},"4":{"name": "Mumbai"}}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var hotels = obj.hotels;
var locations = obj.location;


/* To access hotels */
for (var i in hotels) {
  var hotel = hotels[i];
  console.log(hotel.name + ":" + hotel.description);
}
```

Comment: It is working very good and please explain me the code ? please?

Comment: @HarshadPatil - do you have any JS experience? This is quite basic stuff. I encourage you to read a tutorial on basic JS.